# Animate widget alignment

Tags: flutter

I'm building a custom flexible app bar to use in a `NestedScrollView` and i'm running into issues with the animation.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

In the expanded state, the text is aligned with the top of the Profile picture (in orange), but when the bar collapse, it ends up aligned in the center. I also need all the elements (text + picture) to scale accordingly.

I have access to the current expand factor of the bar using a `LayoutBuilder` and a bit of math

```dart
return LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      double paddingTop = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
      double maxExtent = kExpandedHeight + paddingTop;
      double minExtent = kToolbarHeight + paddingTop;

      final double deltaExtent = maxExtent - minExtent;

      // 0.0 -> Expanded
      // 1.0 -> Collapsed to toolbar
      final double t = (1.0 - (constraints.maxHeight - minExtent) / deltaExtent)
          .clamp(0.0, 1.0);
     // t can be used to animate here
   });
```

I have managed to scale elements with the `Transform` widget and the value of `t` but what I can't figure out is how to animate the switch of alignment of the text part so that it end up perfectly aligned in the center with the picture.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: i would use `AnimatedBuilder` for example (or `TweenAnimationBuilder`)

Comment: You can also try out with AnimatedContainer.

Comment: @pskink @cmd_prompter Both `AnimatedBuilder` and `AnimatedContainer` require a `Animation` which I do not have as I'm working with values directly

Comment: so use `TweenAnimationBuilder` (or `ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget` if you are brave enough) they both create an `Animation` under the hood - all you have to provide is a `Duration`

Comment: @pskink thing is, my animation doesn't depend on a duration, it depend on the size of the header

Comment: @pskink again, my animation doesn't depend on a specific duration, it has to be relative to the current widget height

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
class Act_Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Act_DemoState createState() => _Act_DemoState();
}

class _Act_DemoState extends State<Act_Demo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            TransitionAppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              extent: 150,
              avatar: ListTile(
                title: Text("Name", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                subtitle: Text("abc@gmail.com"),
                trailing: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.orange,radius: 30.0,),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                  return Container(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text("${index}a"),
                      ));
                }, childCount: 25))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

.

```
class TransitionAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget avatar;
  final double extent;
  final Color backgroundColor;

  TransitionAppBar({this.avatar, this.backgroundColor = Colors.transparent, this.extent = 200, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: true,
      delegate: _TransitionAppBarDelegate(
          avatar: avatar,
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          extent: extent > 150 ? extent : 150
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _TransitionAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final _avatarAlignTween = AlignmentTween(begin: Alignment.center, end: Alignment.topCenter);

  final Widget avatar;
  final double extent;
  final Color backgroundColor;

  _TransitionAppBarDelegate({this.avatar, this.backgroundColor, this.extent = 200})
      : assert(avatar != null),
        assert(backgroundColor != null),
        assert(extent == null || extent >= 150);

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    final progress =  shrinkOffset / maxExtent;
    final avatarAlign = _avatarAlignTween.lerp(progress);

    return Container(
      color: backgroundColor,
      child: Align(
        alignment: avatarAlign,
        child: Container(
          child: avatar,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => extent;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 70;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_TransitionAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return avatar != oldDelegate.avatar;
  }
}
```